# How to allow unlimited password attempts in javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
var password;
    var pass1="administrator";
    password=prompt('Please enter password',' ');
    if (password!=pass1)
        alert('password is not currect');

    else
        {
            window.location="home.html";
        }
```

I want to make the number of attempts on the password unlimited

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to keep prompting until they get it, you can use a [do...while](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/do...while)

```js
var password;
var pass1 = "administrator";
do {
  password = prompt('Please enter password', '');
  if (!password) break
  if (password === pass1) {
    window.location = "home.html";
    break; // stop
  } 
  alert('password is not correct');
} while (password != pass1)
```

If you just want them to be allowed to reload and try again

```js
var password;
var pass1 = "administrator";
password = prompt('Please enter password', ' ');
if (password != pass1)
  alert('password is not correct');
else {
  window.location = "home.html";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the else part from your code.

```
var password;
var pass1="administrator";
password = prompt('Please enter password',' ');
if (password!=pass1)
    alert('password is not currect');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code and add breaking statement as you wish to break the loop:

```js
while (true) {
  var password;
  var pass1 = "administrator";
  password = prompt('Please enter password', ' ');
  if (password === null) break;
  if (password != pass1)
    alert('password is not currect');
  else {
    window.location = "home.html";
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: @hack1 try this code and provide feedback

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you want to do, you can use another modal for asking for passwords.
else
if you want to continue with the javascript `prompt` method then you can reload the page while entering the wrong password.

I have added `location.reload();` when condition is false.

```
<script>
  var password;
    var pass1="administrator";
    password=prompt('Please enter password','');
    if (password!=pass1){
        alert('password is not currect');
      location.reload();// reload your page in false condtion.
    }
    else
        {
            window.location="home.html";
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var password=prompt('Please enter password',' ');
var pass1="administrator";
// executes until password==pass1
while (password!=pass1) { 
  alert('password is not correct');
  password=prompt('Please enter password',' ');
}
window.location="home.html";
```